# undefined index mode, which is the variable that case statement is looking for

Tags: php

receiving error: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: mode in /web/ee_web/include/form-modal.php on line 51

line 51

```
switch($_GET["mode"]) {
```

block of code it is in:

```
switch($_GET["mode"]) {
    case "login":
    login_user();
    break;

    case "logout":
    session_destroy();
    print "<p>You are now logged out.</p>";

    print "<p><input type=\"submit\" id=\"closeButton\" name=\"closeButton\" value=\"Close\"  onclick=\"self.parent.tb_remove(); parent.location.reload(1);\" /></p>";
    break;

    default:
    login_user();
    //print "<p>How'd you end up here?</p>";
    break;
}
```

The URL for the page is index.php?mode=logout, that is how I am passing the value into mode.

Any way I could resolve this error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would give a default value for it:

```
if (!isset($_GET['mode']) $_GET['mode'] = "login";

switch($_GET["mode"]) {

    case "logout":

    session_destroy();
    print "<p>You are now logged out.</p>";

    print "<p><input type=\"submit\" id=\"closeButton\" name=\"closeButton\" value=\"Close\"  onclick=\"self.parent.tb_remove(); parent.location.reload(1);\" /></p>";
    break;

    case "login" :    
    default:

    login_user();
    //print "<p>How'd you end up here?</p>";
    break;
}
```

Plus, instead of duplicating the code for `case 'login':` and `default:` you can put them together like that.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it into an if like

```
if( isset($_GET['mode'])) { switch ... } else { print_r($_GET); }
```

to see what are you actually getting.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the problem.  But in the interest of cleaner code + trouble shooting, you might try:

```
$this_mode = $_GET["mode"];
switch($this_mode) {
```

Comment: The 3 answers so far make sense to me, and I would put Kemo's plus mine together

Answer (score 0):

With the combination of url and code, the only thing I can think of is that perhaps you are using a framework that is not allowing GET.

I know that for example CodeIgniter has GET disabled by default.

Doing a `var_dump(GET)` at the top of your page should tell you more as well.